# font-awsome - producing a large icon with text centered below it using :before

Tags: css, position, font-awesome

Can this be done with icon font and :before?

Aim: a large icon centered in a div with a text label centered below it.

The old way I would do this would be a background image and padding-top to render the image above the div content.

Would prefer to use an icon font. Displaying an icon to the left of the text is easy enough using :before but is it possible to display it above instead?

Thanks.

EDIT: I have no code other than bog standard icon font usage:

`.mydiv:before {
    content: "\f11c  "; /* this is the Unicode for the icon */
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    margin-right: .2em;
}`

this places an icon befor the text. Don't even know if possible to posisiton it above instead.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Add the code to the question and then add it to jsFiddle.net for evaluation/testing.

Comment: No code (see edit) looking for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be something like this?

```
.mydiv {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

.mydiv:before {
    content: "\f11c ";    
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: block;
    margin-right: .2em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4W8dg/

Comment: helpful start - problems begin when increasing icon size - so mydiv is 1.4em and .mydiv:before is 6em for example. the icon font breaks out of the div and different icons take up different heights (even at identical font sizes). Currently tweaking line-height to see if this can be addressed.